# Set ajax request in joomla using mootools

Tags: ajax, joomla, mootools

I am having a prob for ajax request in joomla using mootools.

```
 var url = '<?php echo JURI::base();?>index.php?option=com_test&task=getselectmode&selectedid='+$('parent_question').value;

   var params ={method: 'post',update:'test'};
  var myAjax = new Ajax(url, params);
 myAjax.request();
```

My prob is that, is there any to set onComplete event of the ajax request.
i have set it as below on above code but nothing happen.

```
onComplete: function(response) { alert('Response: ' + response); }
```

Can you please provide full code of how to use ajax using mootools 1.1 ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add the onComplete to the params object, no need to add the event seaprately. also, you can use this.response.text. it can all look a bit more compacted - depends on your preference. if you don't plan on reusing the object, just call it direct and don't assign it to a variable either:

```
new Ajax(url, {
    method: "get",
    update: $("someelement"),
    onComplete: function() {
       alert(this.response.text);
    }
}).request();
```

if you do something with the response text, you may want to remove the update: bit. if you need to evaluate the response (as javascript), use evalResponse: true instead of eval(this.response.text);. also handy - evalScripts: true|false if you want to do something from the server side along with the response.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var ajaxObj = new Ajax ('index.php?option=com_yourcomponent&view=yourview&format=raw', {
    method: "get"
});

ajaxObj.addEvent('onComplete', function (data) {
    // data is the response text
    // use as desired
});

// this initiates the call
ajaxObj.request();
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

```
var a = new Ajax( url, {
        method: 'post',
        data: { parfoto: foto },
        onComplete: function( response ){
           ..........
        }
}).request();
```