# Click a link in one module position, an article appears in the other

Tags: module, joomla

Is this possible in Joomla:

I have two modules side by side. In the first one, there's an article with links. When you click on a link, an article appears in the other module. When you click on a different link the first article disappears and a second one appears etc.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

its uncommon but you can do this with JQuery or mootools(better because its native in joomla).

best example with mootools here:
[Set ajax request in joomla using mootools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431179/set-ajax-request-in-joomla-using-mootools)

Comment: Hm, won't that just swap the contents of the modules so the article with the links ends up in module y?

Comment: Yeah, I need the article with the links to stay static while the other module has articles appear and disappear based on what link was clicked. Thanks for the link, though, I'll check it out.